# Как из репозитория сделать insert в бд room

Tags: android, android-room, repository, viewmodel

в репозитории выполняю запрос ретрофитом, не могу разобраться как сделать запись в бд room

класс репозитория

```
public class UserRepository {

    final String TAG ="myLog";
    private String Name;
    private String LastName;
    private String Birthday;
    private String Avatr_url;
    private int number;

    private UserDao mUserDao;
    private LiveData<User> AllUser;
    private RetrofitApi retrofitApi;
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public UserRepository getInstance(){
        if(userRepository == null){
            userRepository = new UserRepository();
        }
        return userRepository;
    }

    public UserRepository(){
        retrofitApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(RetrofitApi.class);
    }

    public UserRepository(Application application){
        Database65 db = Database65.getDatabase65(application);
       mUserDao = db.userDao();
       AllUser = mUserDao.getAll();
       retrofitApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(RetrofitApi.class);
    }

    public LiveData<User> getAllUser(){
        return AllUser;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Response> getNews(){
        MutableLiveData<Response> newsData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        retrofitApi.example()
                .enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, retrofit2.Response<Example> response) {
                        Example example = response.body();


                        int num = example.response.size();

                        for (int i =0; i< num; i++){
                            number = i;
                            //   Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(number));

                            Name = example.response.get(i).fName;
                            LastName = example.response.get(i).lName;
                            Birthday = example.response.get(i).birthday;
                            Avatr_url = example.response.get(i).avatrUrl;

                           /* int siz = example.response.get(i).specialty.size();
                            for (int j = 0; j < siz; j++){
                                Specialty[i] = example.response.get(i).specialty.get(j).name;
                                SpecialtyId[i] = String.valueOf(example.response.get(i).specialty.get(j).specialtyId);
                            }*/
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

        return newsData;
    }
}
```

класс базы данных

```
@Database(entities = {User.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class Database65 extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    private static volatile Database65 INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

    public static final ExecutorService databaseWrieExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    public static Database65 getDatabase65(final Context context){
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Database65.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Database65.class,"database")
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new
            RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db){
            super.onOpen(db);
             databaseWrieExecutor.execute(()->{
             /*   UserDao dao = INSTANCE.userDao();
                User user = new User(1,"Вася", "петров",
                        "12.03.2019", "fsfds");
                dao.insertAll(user);*/
            });
        }
    };
}
```

класс вьюмодель

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {


    private MutableLiveData<Response> mutableLiveData;
    private Response response;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private LiveData<User> AllUser;

    public UserViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        userRepository = new UserRepository(application);
        AllUser = userRepository.getAllUser();
    }

    public void init(){
        if (mutableLiveData != null){
            return;
        }
        userRepository = userRepository.getInstance();
        mutableLiveData = userRepository.getNews();

    }

    public LiveData<User> getAllUser(){
        return AllUser;
    }
}
```

класс Dao

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(User user);

    @Update
    void updateAll(User user);

    @Delete
    void deleteAll(User user);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    LiveData<User> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT*FROM user WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<User> getNam(int id);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам приходит класс `Example`

```
 Example example = response.body();
```

А вам нужно воткнуть `User`

Вы просто делаете что то типа

```
User user = new User(example.Id, example.name )
```

И дальше инсертите как обычно

А если это список , то проходите по нему циклом

что то вроде

```
 for (i in example.indices) {
        val id = example[i].id
        val name = example[i].name
        val item = Item (
            id, name
        )
        database.insert(item)
    }
```

Под рукой был пример на котлине но тут все понятно и

Comment: у меня для ретрофита и для room разные model

Comment: а какая разница какие у вас модели вы просто получаете на выходе обьект, а потом передаете его куда угодно

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это делается очень просто. Есть репозиторий который знает о существовании БД и Сущности, отвечающей за сеть (могут быть и другие если таковые имеются в вашем приложении). Репозиторий получает данные из сети, отдает их вашей ViewModel и сам сохраняет их в БД.

У вас есть некая ошибка в том как вы пытаетесь получить данные из сети. Она заключается в том, что вы хотите вернуть результат синхронно, но сама по себе операция сетевого запроса должна быть асинхронной. Скорее всего в вашем случае вам всегда будет возвращаться пустой список.

**Почему?** Потому что вы отправляете запрос в сеть и не дожидаясь его возвращаете значение. Т.к. програма не будет ждать вашего колбека. Обрабатывать результат вы должны внутри `onResponse()` или `onFailure()`, а значит вы не можете вернуть просто так список ваших данных.

**Решение:**

- Самый простой вариант - Вы можете возвращать из вашего `getNews()` не список, а колбек и обрабатывать его в вашей VM. И оттуда же в `onResponse()` сохранять их в БД. Из минусов вам в репозитории придется иметь какой-то метод для сохранения в БД (Если он будет где-то юзаться отдельно, то норм, если же нет, то получится что будет немного теряться смысл репозитория.
- Второй вариант это подписать вашу VM на репозиторий используюя паттерн Observer. Так VM ничего не нужно будет знать о каких-то сохранениях и вся логика останется в репо. Флоу такой:

  1. При создании VM вы подписываетесь на репо.
  2. Отправляете в репо ваш запрос `getNews()`.
  3. Репо получает ответ и в `onResponse()` он сохраняет в БД ваши данные и оповещает подписчиков (в вашем случае VM) о том что данные получены.
  4. VM получает уведомление и обрабатывает эти данные.
- Ну и последний вариант использовать RX Java, там вы можете всю эту логику вынести в цепочку запросов. Если же вы решите использовать Kotlin, стоит посмотреть в сторону корутин.